# OpenCL - incremental summation during compute

Tags: opencl

I'm absolutelly novice in OpenCL programming. For my app. (molecular simulaton) I wrote a kernel for calculate intermolecular potential of lennard-jones liquid. In this kernel I need to compute cumulative value of the potential of all particles with one:

```
__kernel void Molsim(__global const float* inmatrix, __global float* fi, const int c, const float r1, const float r2, const float r3, const float rc, const float epsilon, const float sigma, const float h1, const float h23)
{
   float fi0;
   float fi1;
   float d;

   unsigned int i = get_global_id(0); //number of particles (typically 2000)

   if(c!=i) {
      // potential before particle movement
      d=sqrt(pow((0.5*h1-fabs(0.5*h1-fabs(inmatrix[c*3]-inmatrix[i*3]))),2.0)+pow((0.5*h23-fabs(0.5*h23-fabs(inmatrix[c*3+1]-inmatrix[i*3+1]))),2.0)+pow((0.5*h23-fabs(0.5*h23-fabs(inmatrix[c*3+2]-inmatrix[i*3+2]))),2.0));
      if(d<rc) {
        fi0=4.0*epsilon*(pow(sigma/d,12.0)-pow(sigma/d,6.0));
      }
      else {
        fi0=0;
      }
      // potential after particle movement
      d=sqrt(pow((0.5*h1-fabs(0.5*h1-fabs(r1-inmatrix[i*3]))),2.0)+pow((0.5*h23-fabs(0.5*h23-fabs(r2-inmatrix[i*3+1]))),2.0)+pow((0.5*h23-fabs(0.5*h23-fabs(r3-inmatrix[i*3+2]))),2.0));
      if(d<rc) {
        fi1=4.0*epsilon*(pow(sigma/d,12.0)-pow(sigma/d,6.0));
      }
        else {
          fi1=0;
        }
      // cumulative difference of potentials
      // fi[0]+=fi1-fi0; changed to full size vector
      fi[get_global_id(0)]=fi1-fi0;
      }
}
```

My problem is in the line: fi[0]+=fi1-fi0;. In the one-element vector fi[0] are wrong results. 
I read something about sum reduction, but I do not know how to do it during the calculation.

Exist any simple solution of my problem?

**Notice**:
I tried to add next kernel for the sum of the vector components (see code below), but there was an even greater slowdown than when I sum vector using the CPU.

```
__kernel void Arrsum(__global const float* inmatrix, __global float* outsum, const int inmatrixsize, __local float* resultScratch)
{
       // načtení indexu
      int gid = get_global_id(0);
      int wid = get_local_id(0);
      int wsize = get_local_size(0);
      int grid = get_group_id(0);
      int grcount = get_num_groups(0);

      int i;
      int workAmount = inmatrixsize/grcount;
      int startOffest = workAmount * grid + wid;
      int maxOffest = workAmount * (grid + 1);
      if(maxOffest > inmatrixsize){
        maxOffest = inmatrixsize;
    }

    resultScratch[wid] = 0.0;
    for(i=startOffest;i<maxOffest;i+=wsize){
            resultScratch[wid] += inmatrix[i];
    }
    barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);

    if(gid == 0){
            for(i=1;i<wsize;i++){
                    resultScratch[0] += resultScratch[i];
            }
            outsum[grid] = resultScratch[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: You need sum reduction here, probably, otherwise it's atomics or serial summation which is going to suck for GPU's. It's a bit difficult to grasp but it's relatively easy to implement (especially if the number of elements to sum is a power of two).

Comment: Consider caching in private memory the values of `inmatrix[i*3+0/1/2]`, since you use it more than once. For the sum, just use a reduction algorithm. That will do the job (as already answered by others)

Answer (score 2):

I think you need the atomic_add atomic function for fi[0]+=fi1-fi0;

Warning: Use an atomic function reduces performance.

Here, two examples with the increment atomic function.

**Example without atomic function and 2 workitems:**

```
__kernel void inc(global int * num){
    num[0]++; //num[0] = 0
}
```

1. Work Item 1 reads num[0]: 0
2. Work Item 2 reads num[0]: 0
3. Work Item 1 increments num[0]: 0 + 1
4. Work Item 2 increments num[0]: 0 + 1
5. Work Item 1 writes num[0]: num[0] = 1
6. Work Item 2 writes num[0]: num[0] = 1

Result : num[0] = 1

**Example with atomic function and 2 workitems:**

```
#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics : enable

__kernel void inc(global int * num){
    atom_inc(&num[0]);
}
```

1. Work Item 1 reads num[0]: 0
2. Work Item 1 increments num[0]: 0 + 1
3. Work Item 1 writes num[0]: num[0] = 1
4. Work Item 2 reads num[0]: 1
5. Work Item 2 increments num[0]: 1 + 1
6. Work Item 2 writes num[0]: num[0] = 2

Result : num[0] = 2

Comment: Atomic functions i ruled out, because fi must be float variable

Comment: A trick [link](http://suhorukov.blogspot.co.uk/2011/12/opencl-11-atomic-operations-on-floating.html)

Answer (score 0):

Atomic add is one solution but you could get performance issues, because the atomic part will serialize your work items.

I think a better solution is, for every work item, to write in their own variable, like:

> fi[get_global_id(0)] +=fi1-fi0;

Then you can either transfer the array to the CPU and sum all elements, or you do it on the GPU with an algorithm to do it in parallel.

Comment: Yes, this is solution. But will reduce perfomance because of serialized sum in host app. Also storing entire array back to CPU memory will be slower than storing one variable.

Answer (score 0):

All your threads are executed by "groups". You can determine thread id in the group using get_local_id(dim) function. Threads within each group can use shared memory (which is called "local memory" in OpenCL) and syncronyze their execution, but threads in different groups cannot communicate directly.

So, the tipical solution for reduction is following:

1. Add temporary arrays part_sum (global) and tmp_reduce (local) to the kernel args:

   ```
   __kernel void Molsim(..., __global float *part_sum, __local float *tmp_reduce)
   ```
2. Allocate array of floats with size equal to number of groups (=global_size/local_size) of your kernel and set parameter part_sum.
3. Set parameter tmp_reduce with your kernel "local size" x size_of(float) and NULL:

   ```
   clSetKernelArg(kernel,<par number>,sizeof(float)*<local_size>,NULL);
   ```
4. In the kernel, replace your code with following:

   ```
     int loc_id=get_local_id(0);

   ...

   //      fi[0]+=fi1-fi0;
          tmp_reduce[loc_id]=fi1-fi0;
         }
      barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
      if(loc_id==0) {
        int i;
        float s=tmp_reduce[0];
        for(i=1;i<get_local_size(0);i++)
          s+=tmp_reduce[i];
        part_sum[get_group_id(0)]=s;
      }
   }
   ```
5. After finishing of kernel execution, just sum on the host the contents of part_sum[array], which is much smaller, than global_size.

This is not fully "parallel reduction", because you can sum tmp_reduce array in parallel using Log2(local_size) operations using more complicated algorithms, but this must be much faster than atomic operations.

Also, look at http://developer.amd.com/Resources/documentation/articles/pages/OpenCL-Optimization-Case-Study-Simple-Reductions_2.aspx for the beter parallel reduction methods.

Comment: In this line, it should be: float s=tmp_reduce **[0]** ? Yet after each time run I get different results